# Passing token in swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

I am new to Swagger.

I am using Swagger UI to generate swagger documentation. I have two API calls. First call is to generate token based on user name and password. Second call needs token generated by first call.

How I set that token for second call using Swagger UI by netcore?

I am using Swagger UI to generate swagger documentation. I have two API calls. First call is to generate token based on user name and password. Second call needs token generated by first call.

Comment: i am using JWT with the second one

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a token issuer (like IdentityServer or open connect ...) and you generate token in backend then you need to add swagger like this (in ConfigureServices method):

```cs
 services.AddSwaggerGen(
                c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Your Api", Version = "v1" });
                    //other options

                    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                    {
                        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (Example: 'Bearer token')",
                        Name = "Authorization",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                        Scheme = "Bearer"
                    });

                    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                    {
                        {
                            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                                }
                            },
                            Array.Empty<string>()
                        }
                    });
                });
```

When run app you should see this button in the swagger

[image]

And when first api generate token you need to paste that token in this format `bearer token`

if you are using a token issuer like `oauth2` you should do some thing like this:

```cs
options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"******"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri($"********")
                          
                        }
                    }
                });
```